# How to delete all the records from cassandra table without creating a snapshot

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-2.1

I am facing a problem with deleting all the  records from a table.

I can use Truncate table. But truncate would create a snapshot of the data which would be a wastage of storage space in my scenario.

Also truncate would fail if any of the nodes are down.

So I would like to know if there is any way to delete all the records in a table without creating a snapshot that works if a node is down.

Answer (score 7):

To alter the behavior of creating a snapshot before truncate you can change your cassandra.yaml

```
# Whether or not a snapshot is taken of the data before keyspace truncation
# or dropping of column families. The STRONGLY advised default of true 
# should be used to provide data safety. If you set this flag to false, you will
# lose data on truncation or drop.
auto_snapshot: true
```

This value is set to true by default. If you don't want this, you can simply set it to false. Just a little warning here, this flag is to make sure that after a drop or a truncate your data is not lost without a second thought. So think really carefully if you really want to disable that feature.

Answer (score -3):

simple use like this

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

public class Truncate_Table {

   public static void main(String args[]){

      //Query
      String query = "Truncate student;";

      //Creating Cluster object
      Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();

      //Creating Session object
      Session session = cluster.connect("tp");

      //Executing the query
      session.execute(query);
      System.out.println("Table truncated");
   }
}
```

i think this will help you

Comment: OP says he does not want to use `truncate` query.

Comment: you can use like this  String query = "DELETE *  FROM  table";

Comment: Then add it to your answer otherwise you might get downvoted. :)

Comment: without condition you can't delete records in this db.DELETE * FROM Table WHERE id = 'some_key_value';

Comment: truncate requires a consistency level of ALL. When one of the nodes in the cluster is down, the program fails with an exception